# If I were to format my hard drive, will I lose my BIOS?

Tags: hard-drive, hp-pavilion

I have **HP Pavilion m6**

First off, I have to format my hard drive because I get this error when I try to install windows:

> Windows cannot be installed on this disk. The selected disk is of the GPT partition style.

I cleaned my HD and converted it from GPT To MBR , then installed windows normally. However, if I shutdown my PC I can't access my new windows. Is BIOS responsible for boot order?

If yes, what should I do?

Answer (score 2):

bios is on the motherboard and among other things it decides which device (read: harddrive, usb stick, or cdrom) should be used for booting. It'll then hand over to code on the boot sector (MBR) of that drive, which'll then boot the system. Most likely you don't have the system set to attempt to boot from the correct drive first.

But no, formatting your drive won't lose your BIOS, the two things are physically distinct systems.

Answer (score 2):

1. Turn on or restart the computer.
2. While the display is blank, press the f10 key to enter the BIOS
   settings menu.
3. Press the f9 key to reset the BIOS to the default settings.
4. Press the f10 key to save the changes and exit the BIOS settings
   menu.

If after another reboot the order is wrong, go into BIOS and set it to the correct device (hard drive). Move the correct drive to the top on the order, or disable certain devices as a "boot device".